# Python script is not listing a file in the directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a slight question.

I have the following function:

```
def getCommands():
    for file in os.listdir(com_dir):
        if file.endswith(com_ext):
            z = string.strip(file, '.gcom')
            print z
```

and in the directory ( Defined by `com_dir` ) there are three files.

`a.gcom`
`b.gcom`
`c.gcom`

when running `getCommands()`

The following is outputted:

`a
 b`

Files a and b are shown ,however, c is not shown, All files are in the directory  and all are using the same file extension: `.gcom` which is also `com_ext` variable wise.

Does anyone have any hints as to why file c is not being shown?

Side note: There seems to be a blank space in the output where `c` should be however Im not sure if this has any part in the issue at hand and isn't just simply a accidental space placed elsewhere in the script.

Comment: Why does the code once say "com_ext", and once "'.gcom'"?

Comment: Whats the **exact** output of `print os.listdir(com_dir)`? And is `com_ext == 'gcom' or com_ext == '.gcom'` true?

Comment: @user770 that was just me being me forgetting I defined that already, but it works either way, I do plan to change it over to the variable `com_ext` though.

Comment: @FHTMitchell the exact output is the three files, `a.gcom` `b.gcom` and `c.gcom`

Comment: No it's not. It's `['a.gcom', 'b.gcom', 'c.gcom']`. Such a simple instruction... Anyway, question answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strip` removes all the given characters from both ends of your string, whatever order they occur in. If your string is `c.gcom`, then `strip('.gcom')` removes all the characters `.`, `g`, `c`, `o` and `m` from the ends of your string, leaving nothing left. It doesn't stop stripping until it hits a character that is not `.`, `g`, `c`, `o` or `m` (or removes everything).

If you have a string ending in `.gcom`, and you just want to remove that ending, you can use:

```
z = file[:-5]
```

or, using your `com_ext` variable

```
com_ext = '.gcom'
...
if file.endswith(com_ext):
    z = file[:-len(com_ext)]
```

Comment: It will remove the characters from both ends, right?

Comment: @plalanne It will, but that's not the point. Even if the OP had used `rstrip` (strip from the right), it would have had the same effect, because the whole string is made of the strippable characters.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem @khelwood

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 does it much better than Python 2:

```
from pathlib import Path

def getCommands(com_dir, com_ext):  # com_ext = "gcom"
    for f in Path(com_dir).glob("*." + com_ext):
        print ("{}".format(f.stem))
```

But if you REALLY have to use Python 2:

```
def getCommands(com_dir, com_ext):
    for file in os.listdir(com_dir):
        s = f.split('.' + com_ext)
        if len(s) > 1:
            print("{}".format(s[0]))
```