# How to strip a string with a "." properly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring, strip

I would like to strip the ending from a string, as in following:

```
da = "abc.com"
print(da.strip(".com"))
```

My expected outcome is `abc`. However, `ab` is returned instead.

Why is that and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `da.replace('.com','')`? Since strip clears all the individual characters contained in '.com' from the string.

Comment: this is because `c` is also contains in `.com`, either use `replace()` or `split()` or `regex`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293407/python-script-is-not-listing-a-file-in-the-directory/50293460#50293460

Comment: The problem is due that the arguments given to `strip` is a list of chars to remove. So you're saying: removing every '.', every 'c' every 'o' every 'm.

Answer (score 2):

this should work: simply split string by `.` and discard the last piece.

```
print(da.split('.')[:-1])
```

Comment: This would work for the provided example but mangle other urls like 'some.thing.abc.com'.

Comment: @meissner_ right. added a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

```
import re
da = "abc.com"
print(re.sub("\.com", "", da))
```

or

```
print(da.replace(".com", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
abc
```